# protect against xss with .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My htaccess redirects everything to my index.php, but i wonder if it's vulnerable to xss attacks. Am i safe?
-- htaccess file
    RewriteBase /

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ index.php/$1 [L]
php_value auto_append_file none
```

-- index.php file ------

```
<?php
require_once 'dbliteconnect.php';
$req['status'] = (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') ? "true" : 'false';
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli' || (isset($_SERVER['argc'])) && $_SERVER['argc'] > 0)     {
$var = isset($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : '';
$var = strreplace("/", "", $var);
$req['var'] = $var;
}
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && php_sapi_name() != 'cli-server') {
$var = strreplace('/'.basename(DIR_), "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$var = str_replace("/", "", $var);
$var = str_replace(".html", "", $var);
$req['var'] = $var;
}
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli-server') {
$var = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$var = substr($var, 1);
$var = strreplace("/", "", $var);
$var = str_replace(".html", "", $var);
$req['var'] = $var;
}
request($req);
?>
```

Comment: This sounds like a request for code review, which isn't generally what this site is for.  Maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Ok, thanks. i'l post it there